# MySQL query modification with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have been trying to get the expected result from this query modification on a single table of multiple tag_ids to pub_ids

```
SELECT t1.pub_id
FROM `wp_teachpress_relation` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `wp_teachpress_relation` AS t2 ON t2.pub_id =356
AND t1.pub_id =1
WHERE t1.pub_id != t2.pub_id
```

The 356 is a the tag id of "united states"
and 1 is the tag id for "university"

I would like all pub_id that have the tag_id(1) university but do not have the tag_id(356) united states... i guess what i'm missing is the fact that this query is ran on the same table ?

example of data and rexpected result :

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.11.11.3
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 68.178.140.228
-- Generation Time: Sep 02, 2013 at 11:08 AM
-- Server version: 5.0.96
-- PHP Version: 5.1.6

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `eco1308903180169`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_teachpress_relation`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_teachpress_relation` (
  `con_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pub_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`con_id`),
  KEY `pub_id` (`pub_id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=25618 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_teachpress_relation`
--

INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_relation` VALUES(10, 10285, 1);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_relation` VALUES(20, 10285, 306);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_relation` VALUES(30, 10286, 1);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_relation` VALUES(40, 10286, 306);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_relation` VALUES(50, 10287, 1);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_relation` VALUES(60, 10287, 356);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_relation` VALUES(62, 10287, 299);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_relation` VALUES(70, 10288, 1);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_relation` VALUES(80, 10288, 356);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_relation` VALUES(90, 10288, 299);
```

ok so running your query on fiddle gave me the right results ... perhaps the issue is from the other joins in the full query ?

```
 SELECT r.tag_id tag_id, t.name name, count( r.tag_id ) tagPeak
FROM (

SELECT t1.pub_id
FROM wp_teachpress_relation AS t1
LEFT JOIN wp_teachpress_relation AS t2 ON t1.pub_id = t2.pub_id
AND t2.tag_id =356
WHERE t1.tag_id =1
AND t2.pub_id IS NULL
)pubs
JOIN `wp_teachpress_relation` r ON pubs.pub_id = r.pub_id
JOIN `wp_teachpress_tags` t ON t.tag_id = r.tag_id
WHERE r.tag_id <>1
AND t.name LIKE 'v%'
GROUP BY tag_id
ORDER BY name ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

additionnal table publications

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.11.11.3
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 68.178.140.228
-- Generation Time: Sep 02, 2013 at 12:51 PM
-- Server version: 5.0.96
-- PHP Version: 5.1.6

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `eco1308903180169`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_teachpress_pub`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_teachpress_pub` (
  `pub_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(500) default NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `bibtex` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `author` varchar(500) default NULL,
  `editor` varchar(500) default NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `url` text,
  `date` date default NULL,
  `urldate` date default NULL,
  `booktitle` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `issuetitle` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `journal` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `volume` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `number` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `pages` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(500) default NULL,
  `address` varchar(300) default NULL,
  `edition` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `chapter` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `institution` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `organization` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `school` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `series` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `crossref` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `abstract` text,
  `howpublished` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `key` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `techtype` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `comment` text,
  `note` text,
  `image_url` varchar(400) default NULL,
  `rel_page` int(11) default NULL,
  `is_isbn` int(1) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`pub_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11764 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_teachpress_pub`
--

INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_pub` VALUES(10285, 'Universidad del Centro Educativo Latinoamericano Rosario', 'misc', 'sc-2014-31', '', '', '', 'http://www.ucel.edu.ar/', '2012-06-22', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 1);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_pub` VALUES(10286, 'Universidad del Cine - Buenos Aires', 'misc', 'sc-2014-32', '', '', '', 'http://www.ucine.edu.ar/', '2012-06-22', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 1);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_pub` VALUES(10287, 'Instituto Universitario Aeronáutico', 'misc', 'sc-2014-33', '', '', '', 'http://www.iua.edu.ar/', '2012-06-22', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 1);
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_pub` VALUES(10288, 'Universidad del Museo Social Argentino', 'misc', 'sc-2014-34', '', '', '', 'http://www.umsa.edu.ar/', '2012-06-22', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 1);
```

additional tag table

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.11.11.3
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 68.178.140.228
-- Generation Time: Sep 02, 2013 at 01:02 PM
-- Server version: 5.0.96
-- PHP Version: 5.1.6

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `eco1308903180169`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_teachpress_tags`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_teachpress_tags` (
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(300) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=357 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_teachpress_tags`
--

INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_tags` VALUES(306, 'Chile');
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_tags` VALUES(64, 'China');
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_tags` VALUES(365, 'United states');
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_tags` VALUES(1, 'university');
INSERT INTO `wp_teachpress_tags` VALUES(299, 'california');
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing up `pub_id` and `tag_id` in your query.

Comment: Is tag_id a number or a string? I was hoping you would post a table I can copy into sqlfiddle.com. Can you make a sqlfiddle, please?

Comment: Ok I will figure out how to output sample data from phpmyadmin... the table is to large for a full export that can be pasted in sqlfiddle ... (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8)

Comment: Just export those 15 rows, but in raw numeric form.

Comment: Well, now that you've changed the question, we need some sample data from the 2 new tables, and what you expect vs what you're getting.

Comment: Ok I hear you, I was thinking that by changing the base select for tag_id=1 (as per my initial question) i would be able to limit end results of the full query (second question) ... your initial suggestion narrows the results on there own but not once i place it in the full query ... could you "suggest" a solution based on the full query please. If not thank you for your time. jf

Comment: To me it seems the issue in the full query is with this line : JOIN `wp_teachpress_tags` t ON t.tag_id = r.tag_id ... basically getting the tag names but not base on the limited pubs query ?! makes sens

Comment: I agree. If you provide some data, I can probably figure out how to make that right.

Comment: ok... I tried to make the ids match for the relation with 3 tables...

Comment: There are no names in `wp_teachpress_tags` that match `v%`. I changed Chile to Venezuela, got result 306 Venezuela 2.

Comment: See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2dcb/1

Comment: hummm if I run the same second query on the db I get : `tag_id  name  tagPeak
325  Venezuela  37
326  Vermont  2
327  Vietnam  40
328  Virgin Islands  1
329  Virginia  4`

Comment: That's because the fiddle only has a small portion of your database. Are those results right or wrong? If they're wrong, what SHOULD the results be?

Comment: the result should be just countries with no US states... so just Venezuela, Vietnam, virgin Island

Comment: If you can update my fiddle with more data, maybe I can figure it out.

Comment: How can I send you my db accesss... ?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good idea. Can't you copy some of the Virginia and Vermont entries into the fiddle?

Comment: to me it seems like some entries in table pub are not taged with 356 (united states) so when joined they pass US states tag with them in final result. I'm not able to compose queries to trouble shoot this.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out :)

Comment: hummm true... but surprisingly all the publication listed in the front-end result here : (http://ecoaxis.ca/ressorce-pages/universities-specifics/?tgid=4&alpha-search=A&yr=&type=&auth=) have the united states tag 356 ... i just don't know how to present all the tables to you to reproduce this on fiddle ...

Comment: If SO had a private message system I'd send you my email so you could send me dumps of the tables. But I'm not posting it here, sorry.

Comment: I figured why not try and remove all tag_id of each states... so instead of r.tag_id <>1 ... i added r.tag_id not in (2,45,5,78,321,...) ... certainly know more about joins now Barmar ;-) thank you for helping out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard LEFT JOIN idiom, you should learn it:

```
SELECT t1.pub_id 
FROM wp_teachpress_relation AS t1 
LEFT JOIN wp_teachpress_relation AS t2 ON t1.pub_id = t2.pub_id and t2.tag_id = 356
WHERE t1.tag_id = 1
and t2.pub_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Nice of you to have a look at this with me ... I'm still getting both full result sets (all universities and all universities from the US) where I would like all universities not from US ... this will give me SELECT pub_id
FROM `wp_teachpress_relation`
WHERE `tag_id` =356 ... will give me all US pub with tag US (or `tag_id` =1) will give me all pubs with university tags...

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired results?

Comment: you can also view the original query printed out here: (http://ecoaxis.ca/ressorce-pages/universities-specifics/?tgid=326&alpha-search=V&yr=0&type=&auth=0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.pub_id 
FROM wp_teachpress_relation AS t1 
LEFT JOIN wp_teachpress_relation AS t2 ON t1.pub_id = t2.pub_id 
WHERE t1.pub_id = 1
group by t1.pub_id 
HAVING count(t2.pub_id = 356) = 0
```

Comment: Then please post your table structure, example data and expected output.